# Refactoring inline JS is giving error in rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have an inline script in my rails ERB view:

```
<script>
      $("#new_assessment").find('input[name=commit]').on('click', function(e){
              ...



             $.ajax({
                url: "/assessments",
                type: "POST",
                data: {assessment:{template_id, patient_id, answers}},
                success: console.log("success"),
                error: function(err) {
                  console.log("error");
                }
             });



      });

</script>
```

But I want to re-use this script, so I moved it to assets/js/form-script.js like:

```
       $(function(){

console.log("yay")
              $("#new_assessment").find('input[name=commit]').on('click', function(e){
                      ...



                     $.ajax({
                        url: "/assessments",
                        type: "POST",
                        data: {assessment:{template_id, patient_id, answers}},
                        success: console.log("success"),
                        error: function(err) {
                          console.log("error");
                        }
                     });



              });

     });
```

But the second code doesn't work (even though the "yay" loads). How can I transfer the first inline script into it's own separate JS file without losing functionality?

Comment: What's the exact error message or is nothing happening when you click the input? [respond by editing the question please]

Comment: Also you are assigning the return value of `console.log("success")` (undefined) as the success handler. It should be `success: function(){ console.log("success") }`